# PHP script execution in Firebase?

Tags: php, ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, subscription

Here's my scenario: I have 10 ios apps with subscription in app purchases. I need one subscription purchase to be valid accross the 10 apps. Thus I require server-side receipt validation. The flow is like this: When the customer pays for the subscription, the receipt is sent to the Firebase DB and from there, I **require a PHP script that takes in the receipt data . as input and sends a 'POST' request to the App store. The App store would then validate the receipt and return a JSON object back.** We then overwrite the old receipt with the latest copy. Also, whenever the user logs in to any of the apps, we repeat this process and update the receipt to make sure the subscription of the user is still valid. My question is, is Firebase capable of dynamic script handling and HTTP requests?

Thanks :) for any help.

Comment: Is there an alternative cloud service I could use to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Hosting cannot execute PHP scripts. It mostly a static hosting service (so serving uninterpreted HTML, JavaScript, CSS, etc).

Recently Firebase added the ability to [connect Cloud Functions to Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). But that still doesn't allow you to run PHP code on Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank! Are you aware of some good cloud services that would offer such functionality? And which one do you think would be the best and easy to work with?